# What does he say in this audio? "I haven't seen you since..."

Tags: listening

Please listen to [this audio clip](http://vocaroo.com/i/s1u5xAqwUR8w) and tell me what the man says.

> He says: I haven't seen you since...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are not really a transcription service.

Answer (score 2):

The audio is

> Hey, I haven't seen you since you went off to art school.

Comment: thanks but I hear a 'sh' sound there

Comment: @amin Peter's transcription is correct.  If you're having trouble distinguishing the 's' sound from the 'sh' sound in this clip, that might be due to an artifact of the recording / encoding rather than the actual pronunciation.